# MULE:: Not able to archive/delete file in an FTP location

Tags: ftp, mule

I have defined a FTP outbound to move a file to an archive folder, the file gets archived but never gets deleted from the source location. Due to this the same files keeps getting processed again and again. Any ideas why its not removing from the source location???

```
<ftp:connector name="ftp-inbound" pollingFrequency="90000"  validateConnections="true" doc:name="FTP"/>
<ftp:connector name="ftp-outbound" pollingFrequency="200000" validateConnections="true" doc:name="FTP"/>

<flow name="ftp_import_flow" processingStrategy="synchronous"> 
    <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="21" responseTimeout="100000" doc:name="FTP" connector-ref="ftp-inbound" password="test123" path="/ftpSource/" user="admin"> 
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="*.csv" caseSensitive="true"/>  
        <set-variable variableName="originalFileName" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="Variable"/>  
        <logger message="FileName: #[originalFileName]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>  
        <reconnect frequency="100000" count="2"/>  
    </ftp:inbound-endpoint>  

    <byte-array-to-string-transformer name="byte_array_to_string" doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>  

    <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="21" connector-ref="ftp-outbound" 
            responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" password="test123" path="/ftpSource/archive/" user="admin"> 
        <reconnect frequency="100000" count="2"></reconnect>  
    </ftp:outbound-endpoint>  

    <logger message="#[message]" level="DEBUG" category="ftp_flow" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  

    <scripting:component doc:name="ftp"> 
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="file.groovy"></scripting:script>  
    </scripting:component>  

    <logger message="#[payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger" category="ftp_flow" />  

    <foreach doc:name="For Each"> 
        <flow-ref name="insert_mysql_flow" doc:name="insert_mysql_flow" />
    </foreach>  

    <logger message="File Process Successful" level="INFO" category="ftp_flow" doc:name="Log completion"/>  


</flow>
```

Comment: What version of mule server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the option "Delete files after processing" on the Advanced tab in FTP inbound connector.

[image]

Comment: This works for files having smaller record count like 1000 rows. But when the file is having more than 2000 rows the file never gets deleted and I see the exception "FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection."

Comment: By the way I set the "Delete files after processing" for ftp:outbound-endpoint where I archive the file. If I do this inbound it gets archived and deleted even before the records are processed.